# Where my log statement is printing on Mac?

Tags: xcode, macos, logging, firefox-addon

I have an firefox extension with the name myjavascriptfile.js,As I am new to this addon concepts,just I want to debug this script.So I am using the following statements in this file like

```
function LOG(text)
{
    var consoleService = Components.classes["@mozilla.org/consoleservice;1"].getService(Components.interfaces.nsIConsoleService);
    consoleService.logStringMessage(text);
}


observe: function(subject, topic, data)
    {
      LOG("observe called ");
}
```

I know this observe is getting called but I dont know where to see my log message.can some one tell me Where it is printing?
Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That text goes to the Error Console. You might need to go to `about:config` and change `devtools.errorconsole.enabled` preference to `true` - the Error Console was removed from the menus by default while ago (strangely enough, I could still see it even without this pref). I think that on OS X you can still open the Error Console via Tools / Web Developer menu, on Windows you have to click the Firefox button and choose Web Developer menu there. Alternatively, Command-Shift-J should do as well.